# Looking to vectorize P2 Penrose tiling

Tags: tiling

I'm looking for a tool to vectorize a P2 Penrose tiling.

I've been able to find tools to vectorize P3 tilings, but not P2.

Goal is to put p2 tiling on cycling kit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The [part of the Wikipedia page on Penrose tilings describing the P2 tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling#Kite_and_dart_tiling_(P2)) has [a vector image of the pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kite_Dart.svg) under a creative commons license. Can you clarify how that does not meet your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [part of the English Wikipedia page on Penrose tilings describing the P2 tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling#Kite_and_dart_tiling_(P2)) has [a vector image of the pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kite_Dart.svg) and [a vector image of the vertex figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_vertex_figures.svg), both under the [Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported Creative Comments license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

**Edit:** For images of a significant P2 tiling, rather than just the pieces or vertex figures, here are some resources. Except for the first point, I found them by searching Google for `penrose kite and dart vector` or `penrose kite and dart svg`:

- If you don't need too much of a tiling, Wikipedia has [a "sun" svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_sun_3.svg) (mentioned on the [vertex figures page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_vertex_figures.svg) linked above) and [a "star" svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_star_3.svg).
- [Sarah Marsh](https://github.com/sarahmarshy/) has a Python program [PenroseGenerator](https://github.com/sarahmarshy/PenroseGenerator) on [GitHub](https://github.com/) which generates svg files for tilings.
- [Jeff Preshing's blog](https://preshing.com/about/) has [a tutorial and Python code](https://preshing.com/20110831/penrose-tiling-explained/) for generating tilings.
- [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code)'s [page for Penrose tiling](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) has code for tilings in a variety of languages, most or all of which are for P2 tilings.
- [Jonas Arnfred](https://github.com/arnfred) has [a **convenient tiling generator** on the web](http://penrose.dynkarken.com/) that lets you download svg files and which has [a corresponding GitHub page](https://github.com/arnfred/Penrose).

Comment: I'm looking for a vector image of the whole tiling. I'm looking to put it on cycling kit for my team.

Comment: @Retiredaccount that context would be good to add to your question post. I've added some more resources to my answer.